# React Native - TouchableOpacity onPressOut not work inside FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I put `TouchableOpacity` in `FlatList` inside `ListHeaderComponent Props`, when I call `onPressOut` methods, it's not triggered. It's work on Expo, but in cli it's not work
I hope it's not a bug so i can keep working with flatlist.
https://snack.expo.io/@gigapudding/hello-world . 
update when i run on android, it's not work either

```
 <View style={{flex:1}} >
      <FlatList
                onScroll={(data)=>{
                  console.log(data.nativeEvent)
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item)=>item.id.toString()}
                ref={(ref)=>this.flatList=ref}
                style={{
                  position  : 'absolute',
                  top       : 0,
                  height    : wHeight,
                  width     : width,
                }}
                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                ListHeaderComponent={()=>(
                  <View
                    style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}
                  >
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        activeOpacity={1}
                        onPressIn={()=>{
                          console.log('in')
                          this.setState({cameraButton:true})
                        }}
                        onPressOut={()=>{
                          console.log('out')
                          this.setState({cameraButton:false})
                        }}

                        style={[
                          {
                            width         : width*0.15,
                            height        : width*0.15,
                            borderRadius  : 100,
                            borderWidth   : 1,
                            borderColor   : '#fff',
                          },
                          this.state.cameraButton&&{backgroundColor:'#fff'}
                        ]}
                      />
                    </View>
                )}
              />
  </View>
```

Comment: did you found any solution? i am having same issue .